# How to pass dateformat as an argument to the Mysqldb execute method

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, mysql-python

For escaping the % we can do as below.

```
cur.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(END_DATE, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') FROM  CALENDAR_DETAILS", ())
```

But any idea, how to pass the dateformat to the execute method as below?

```
cur.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(END_DATE, %s) FROM  CALENDAR_DETAILS", "%%Y-%%m-%%d")
```

I am getting result for cur.fetchone() as '%Y-%m-%d' instead of the formated date value for the second statement.

Many Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "getting as result"? can you show `cur._executed`?

Comment: @TalKremerman cur._executed gives string without espcaping % as "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(END_DATE, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') FROM CALENDAR_DETAILS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version - use:

```
cur.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(END_DATE, %s) FROM  CALENDAR_DETAILS", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Long(er) version:

`execute` formats the query string, so when you have `%` in your query - you need to escape them (your first line).
However, when the `%` is not in the query but rather in the parameter - there's no need for escaping. 
When you run:

```
cur.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(END_DATE, %s) FROM  CALENDAR_DETAILS", "%%Y-%%m-%%d")
```

The query executed is

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(END_DATE, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') FROM CALENDAR_DETAILS
```

i.e. You escape the format IN the format you give to the sql server. It's just like giving a format of '7777' - you always get '7777' - so in this case you always get %Y-%m-%d.